# Can't build dockerfile with Pulumi

Tags: docker, go, dockerfile, pulumi

I'm trying to build a docker file with Pulumi. I have the following Pulumi code

```golang
func main() {
    pulumi.Run(func(ctx *pulumi.Context) error {
        imageName := "server"
        _, err = docker.NewImage(ctx, imageName, &docker.ImageArgs{
            ImageName: pulumi.Sprintf("gcr.io/gadic-310112/%s:latest", imageName),
            SkipPush: pulumi.Bool(true),
            Build: &docker.DockerBuildArgs{
                Dockerfile: pulumi.String("Dockerfile"),
            },
        })
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }

    }
}
```

However, when I run `pulumi preview` I get the following error:

```
Diagnostics:
  pulumi:pulumi:Stack (server-prod):
    error: program failed: docker build -f Dockerfile . -t gcr.io/gadic-310112/server:latest failed with error: exit status 1
    exit status 1

    error: an unhandled error occurred: program exited with non-zero exit code: 1

  docker:image:Image (server):
    error: #1 [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile
    #1 sha256:921a08a3c227abd8c3811effc689fa5319db237c32a4adf2b255007a51af9ef8
    #1 transferring dockerfile: 2B 0.0s done
    #1 DONE 0.0s
    failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to read dockerfile: open /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount052159980/Dockerfile: no such file or directory
```

What's interesting is that it seems Pulumi is running `docker build -f Dockerfile . -t gcr.io/gadic-310112/server:latest` under the hood. And when I run that from my terminal it succeeds without any error.

```
 ❯❯❯ docker build -f Dockerfile . -t gcr.io/gadic-310112/server:latest
[+] Building 11.3s (16/18)
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                   0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 1.87kB                                                                                                                                                                 0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => => transferring context: 34B                                                                                                                                                                       0.0s
....
```

It seems that Pulumi might be using a different working directory than the place where it's getting invoked from. Is that possible? Is there something else that might be going on?

I've noticed that if I don't include a `Dockerfile` in the `DockerBuildArgs` then the command generated by pulumi is `docker build -f  . -t gcr.io/gadic-310112/server:latest` which is definitely incorrect. If I execute that command locally I get the following:

```
 ❮❮❮ docker build -f  . -t gcr.io/gadic-310112/server:latest
"docker build" requires exactly 1 argument.
See 'docker build --help'.

Usage:  docker build [OPTIONS] PATH | URL | -

Build an image from a Dockerfile
```

EDIT: I also tried passing the absolute path to the folder containing my Dockerfile as the `Context` of the `BuildArgs`

```golang
            Build: &docker.DockerBuildArgs{
                Dockerfile: pulumi.String("Dockerfile"),
                Context: pulumi.String("/Users/paymahn/gadic/server"),
            },
```

and this still gets the same error as before, even though the underlying `docker build` command has an absolute path:

```
Diagnostics:
  docker:image:Image (server):
    error: #1 [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile
    #1 sha256:16f11ab26c775f06385c0fde07864ed70b428d13662aa2be42823751fb5143f4
    #1 transferring dockerfile: 2B 0.0s done
    #1 DONE 0.1s
    failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to read dockerfile: open /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount684750851/Dockerfile: no such file or directory

  pulumi:pulumi:Stack (server-prod):
    error: program failed: docker build -f Dockerfile /Users/paymahn/gadic/server -t gcr.io/gadic-310112/server:latest failed with error: exit status 1
    exit status 1

    error: an unhandled error occurred: program exited with non-zero exit code: 1
```

EDIT 2: Here's the layout of my files

```
/Users/paymahn/gadic/server/
                            infra/
                                  main.go # this is the go program that pulumi runs
                            src/ # this is where the source code for my server lives
                            Dockerfile
                            Pulumi.yaml
                            Pulumi.prod.yaml # the pulumi stack config
                            go.sum
                            go.mod
                            .git/ # this is the root of my git repository
```

Comment: Can you also share the layout of your directory, ie where your Dockerfile is and where your files are.

Comment: Totally, I'll add that as an edit right now. EDIT: done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Pulumi projects builds inside your `infra` directory, not in the folder your `Pulumi.yaml` is in.

The Pulumi provider needs to know the path of the `Dockerfile` using the docker build context (more info about these [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/))

Adding the context should fix this:

```
func main() {
    pulumi.Run(func(ctx *pulumi.Context) error {
        imageName := "server"
        _, err = docker.NewImage(ctx, imageName, &docker.ImageArgs{
            ImageName: pulumi.Sprintf("gcr.io/gadic-310112/%s:latest", imageName),
            SkipPush: pulumi.Bool(true),
            Build: &docker.DockerBuildArgs{
                Dockerfile: pulumi.String("Dockerfile"),
                Context: "../", # note I'm adding the context here
            },
        })
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have intuition for why setting a context to the absolute path of the folder containing my Dockerfile didn't work?